# Apache flink kubernetes operator - Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3p'

Tags: apache-flink

I am very new to flink and I am trying to setup flink operator with s3 presto file system on a self managed k8s cluster running on EC2s.
I have modified the Dockerfile to copy over the presto jar file to plugins directory and Ive also added the below in the configmap.

```
    state.checkpoints.dir: s3p://test-flink-rocksdb/flink/
    s3.access-key: DDD
    s3.secret-key: DDD
    execution.checkpointing.interval: 10000
```

I have also added the env variable - `ENABLE_BUILT_IN_PLUGINS=flink-s3-fs-presto-1.17.1.jar`

Then I am trying to run this sample job https://github.com/apache/flink-kubernetes-operator/blob/main/examples/basic-session-deployment-only.yaml

I am getting this error in the job's logs
`Caused by: org.apache.flink.core.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemSchemeException: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3p'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugin(s): flink-s3-fs-presto.`

Comment: Where did you copy the presto plugin? It must be copied to the `plugins/s3-fs-presto` directory and not only the `plugins` directory.